# Compare 2 List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#

I have a function which returns a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` where object is a standard type (string, int, etc).

I need to take a second `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` and ensure that All entries in list B are represented in List A (order in the list does not matter).

Currently I have code that looks like this:

```
foreach(Dictionary<string, object> rowResult in A) {
  foreach(Dictionary<string, object> rowCompare in B) {
    foreach(string columnName in rowResult.Keys) {
       // ... logic to compare columns
    }
  }

  // ...logic to compare rows so we dont find the same row twice.
}
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

We dont care that all rows in rowResult are found, but all rows in rowCompare must be. It **is** ok to remove rows from the compare or result set to make the iteration easier.

My code works, it just looks over complicated and fragile.

Comment: Its not homework. Its for comparing ad-hoc row sets. I didnt want to add all the compare logic as its not really relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: No problem, SLaks was just making sure all bases were covered.

Comment: All good, just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> {    
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> x, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> y) {
        if (x == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
        }
        if (y == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
        }
        if (x.Count != y.Count) {
            return false;
        }           
        foreach (var kvp in x) {
            TValue value;
            if(!y.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value)) {
                return false;
            }
            if(!kvp.Value.Equals(value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }
        int hash = 0;
        foreach (var kvp in obj) {
            hash = hash ^ kvp.Key.GetHashCode() ^ kvp.Value.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public bool Contains(
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> first,
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> second) {
    if(first == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
    }
    if(second == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
    }
    IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, object>> comparer = new DictionaryComparer<string, object>();
    return second.All(y => first.Contains(y, comparer));
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I had forgotten about implementing my own hash.

Comment: fyi MS.NET 3.5 doc for "IEqualityComparer<(Of <(T>)>) Interface" : "We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer<(Of <(T>)>) class instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer<(Of <(T>)>) interface, because the EqualityComparer<(Of <(T>)>) class tests for equality using the IEquatable<(Of <(T>)>)..::.Equals method instead of the Object..::.Equals method. This is consistent with the Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove methods of the Dictionary<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) class and other generic collections" : that comment is not in current FrameWork 4 docs. Hope that's relevant.

Comment: There's an error in public bool Equals(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> x, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> y)

Should be 
....
if(!y.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out value))

Comment: @Michał Drozdowicz: Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Well... what are you doing this *for*? The reason I ask is that there's this hyper useful Unit Testing method called [CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequivalent(VS.80).aspx).

From the remarks section:

> Two collections are equivalent if they have the same elements in the same quantity, but in any order. Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object.

It looks like it does exactly what you want, and throws AssertFailedException if the two are not equivalent, which may also be what you want. Is there any way to leverage it? One method call is certainly far greater than a triple-nested loop -- even if that's what the method does under the covers.

Comment: I have a system which returns results as a List<Dictionary<string, object>> the data is a fixed set, and I need to ensure that a subset of that data exists. A =/= B, but B == A(sub) [some subset of A] this is also true of the Dictionary<string, object> as well (B might have less entries, but all entries must be in A)

Comment: I did check that out. Very interesting, not something for this job but good info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Dictionary<string, object> rowCompare in B)
    if(!A.Contains(rowCompare)) return false;
return true;
```

Assuming your comparators are set up appropriately, this will work. And is straightforward and easy to understand. You can even add the braces back in if you find it easier that way.

Comment: I am not sure that actually compares the contents of the dictionaries. I had similar code and it was always returning false.

Each key in the dictionary needs to be compared with its corresponding key in the other dictionary.

I will give it a try.

Comment: You almost surely have to set up a custom `IEqualityComparer` for this to work

Comment: There is a reason I included the phrase *Assuming your comparators are set up appropriately* in my answer.

Comment: First, I think you added that while I was making my comment; I'm sorry if I overlooked it. Second, I'm pretty sure that you _have_ to set up a custom `IEqualityComparer` here so that the default will absolutely not work.

Comment: I know I can set up my own comparer, I was hoping to avoid writing code unnecessarily.

Comment: While creating a custom `IEqualityComparer` for this is the better method, it is possible to do the same by subclassing `Dictionary`, if you have complete control over what goes into `A`.

Comment: I'm not sure how writing an comparer would be "unnecessary" code. In fact, it saves on code writing if you have to do the same equality test in more than one place.